# Webview to load while slashscreen is on

Tags: java, android, webview

Quite new to android studio but i'm facing a problem where my *WebView* is taking too long to load, so i've created a splashscreen for 4 seconds and plan to cover the loading using this splash screen. But I dont really know how to let it overlap so the *WebView* can load behind the splashscreen.
 the java for my splash screen

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

BottomBar mBottomBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

}

}
```

then i also have a bottombar that navigates to the first framgment with the webview and the java are as below
    public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
BottomBar mBottomBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this,savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main,new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int i) {
            if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemone) {
                    HomeFragment f = new HomeFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f).commit();
            }
            else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemtwo)
            {
                SearchFragment f =new SearchFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }
            else if(i==R.id.Bottombaritemthree)
            {
                AccountFragment f =new AccountFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,f).commit();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int i) {

        }
    });
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0,"#F2F2F2");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1,"#F2F2F2");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2,"#F2F2F2");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and finally the java for my webview in the first HomeFragment

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    WebView my2WebView;

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup        container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home,container,false);
    getLoaderManager();
    my2WebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = my2WebView.getSettings();
    my2WebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
    webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.getLoadsImagesAutomatically();
    my2WebView.loadUrl("http://www.fidellaglobal.com/feed");
    my2WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    return view;

}
```

so what can i do to making the webview in the first fragment to load when the splashscreen is on ? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Initially set your *WebView* visibility invisible inside your layout file. Add you *WebView* in same screen which have delay Handler.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Make your webview visible
       mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
},SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```